# LDAP Authentication - connection string

Tags: 2010, claims-based-auth, ldap

I am setting up claims auth for a site which needs to use LDAP. The connection needs to be made using a certain user account so I need to pass in the password. Does anybody has an example of a connection string that includes a password? I am using the following example to setup the ldap auth:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2009/11/05/configuring-forms-based-authentication-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

And the similar membership and role provider info on that link. Sorry cant copy the info on this post, the editor won't allow it maybe because of the XML format.

Thanks!

Comment: Found this technet forum post(http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010setup/thread/968fc92c-132c-4dde-ad41-10172808f715)where the OP posted his configuration which has the username and password format, will try that out and let you guys know.

Comment: That would be the correct way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the link provided by Emon is broken, so I thought I'd provide a configuration here:

```
<add name="ldapmembership" 
type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Security.LdapMembershipProvider, Microsoft.Office.Server, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,          PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"  
    server="xxxx"
    port="389" 
    useSSL="false" 
    userDNAttribute="uid" 
    userNameAttribute="uid" 
    userContainer="DC=xxxxx" 
    userObjectClass="person" 
    userFilter="(ObjectClass=person)" 
    scope="Subtree"
    useDNAttribute="false"  
    otherRequiredUserAttributes="uid,cn"
    connectionUsername="uid=xxxxx,OU=xxx,OU=xxxx,DC=xxxx"
    connectionPassword="xxxxx" />
```